# Drawing the PNG image on the window - C++ SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I've created a window, but the image don't render on it

I have tried a lot of things, but none worked.

Here is part of the program

```
janela1 = SDL_CreateWindow("Arkanoid", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, janx, jany, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(janela1, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
rwop = SDL_RWFromFile("bola.png", "rb");
textura = IMG_LoadTexture_RW(rend, rwop, NULL);
if (textura == nullptr || rwop == nullptr){
    cout << "erro";
}
SDL_Rect textura_retangulo;
textura_retangulo.h = 100;
textura_retangulo.w = 100;
textura_retangulo.x = 100;
textura_retangulo.y = 100;
SDL_RenderClear(rend);
SDL_RenderCopy(rend, textura, NULL, &textura_retangulo);
SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
```

I think the problem was in the RenderCopy, I don't know if is needed to do something else to render the image, because in the way is now nothing happen

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Do all of the SDL functions return without error values?

Answer (score 0):

First of, you should declare the int values of janx and jany before declaring the window.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio> 

int janx = 100; //change both of these into your preferred number
int jany = 100;

SDL_Window *janela1 = SDL_CreateWindow("Arkanoid", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, janx, jany, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(janela1, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
SDL_Texture *textura = IMG_LoadTexture_RW(rend, rwop, NULL);
SDL_RWops *rwop = SDL_RWFromFile("bola.png", "rb");
SDL_Event()* mainEvent = new SDL_Event();

if (textura == nullptr || rwop == nullptr){
    cout << "erro";
}
SDL_Rect textura_retangulo;
textura_retangulo.h = 100;
textura_retangulo.w = 100;
textura_retangulo.x = 100;
textura_retangulo.y = 100;


//I highly recommend you turn these into a loop, you'll find trouble once this expands.
void loop()
{
    while(mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT)
    {
         SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
         SDL_RenderClear(rend);
         SDL_RenderCopy(rend, textura, NULL, &textura_retangulo);
         SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    }
}
```